# Full stop following initials (British English)

Tags: british-english

I am purchasing a gift for a colleague, a pen with his name engraved on it.

Unfortunately my command over language has declined significantly since I last studied English during my GCSEs!

I was wondering for British English what would be the correct way to get his name engraved on the pen.

The first name is James Daniel. The surname is Atkins. He is a doctor by profession.

Would it be Dr. J. D. Atkins

Dr J. D. Atkins

Dr. J D Atkins

Dr J D Atkins

Any other combination that I may be missing ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! With all this covid on our minds, it's one less thing to worry about haha

Comment: The Oxford University Style Guide recommends your fourth one: Dr J D Atkins. Three spaces and no dots.

Comment: There are other threads containing the 'answer', though the questions do not have exactly the same wording. But (a) 'BrE' is not well-defined, different styles being used in different UK institutions, companies, pubs etc; (b) I can't see anyone in the UK nowadays thinking that option (4) is either incorrect according to some thousand-year-old shibboleth, or unstylish.